# Setting scope properties in link function

Tags: angularjs

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/_miki_/pen/RLMKKV).

What do I have to do to make scope.test visible in my HTML when I give my directive an isolated scope, replacing "scope: false" with "scope: {}"?

My directive:

```
angular
  .module("MyApp", [])
  .directive("myDir", () => {
    return {
      scope: false,
      restrict: "A",
      link: (scope, element) => {
          scope.test = 'my test';
      }
    };
  });
```

My HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div my-dir>{{test}}</div>
</div>
```

No Controller, only link function in my directive.

Comment: Seems to be working for me, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lkx1RLf5neaLG0IaWAgm?p=preview), even in [codepen](https://codepen.io/_miki_/pen/RLMKKV)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. Let me clarify; my codepen works with "scope: false", but when I give the directive a new scope, setting "scope: {}" the scope variables are not visible in the HTML anymore.

Comment: With isolated scope the only way is to use $parent ref: `scope.$parent.test = 'my test';`

Comment: When I followed the the link the first time, I got {{test}}. After a refresh it shows 'my test'. A timing issue maybe?

Comment: @zgue Absolutely no, that happen because you were editing live plunker perhaps. Look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier it had work because you had `scope: false` (shared scope).

In your case adding `scope: {}` to directive wouldn't reflected `test` value changes on screen. Because when `scope: {}` isolated scope created in directive, it binds that `scope` to the directive `template` if it present. In your case you don't have any `template` in your directive.

If you wanted to see input value you could change it by

1. Either using `$parent` convention like scope.$parent.test = 'my test'
2. OR shift the `{{test}}` inside directive template so that isolated scope will get compiled with directive template.

Answer (score 1):

In basic words `scope:false` means - directive takes the same scope of controller from where it was called.

On other hand `scope:{}` is a *isolate scope* and it uses internal scope of directive and its effected on directive template only

---

You can try to play with `ng-transclude` something like:

```
<div my-dir>{{$parent.test}}</div>
```

and:

```
  .directive("myDir", () => {
    return {
      scope: {},
      transclude: true,
      restrict: "A",
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
      link: (scope, element) => {
          scope.test = 'my test';
      }
    };
  });
```

<kbd>[Codepan Demo](https://codepen.io/Fess-81/pen/dVmNwR?editors=1010)</kbd>